# How to make a button stop submitting forms after the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My trouble is that I have a form whit a submit button, but if you do more than a click it keeps adding the same info as the first one, how can I stop this? How can I disable the button after the first click?

**The code of the button**

---

```
function onAddClick(id){
    $("#AccountAddModal").modal('toggle');
}
var AddForm = $("#add-form");
AddForm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/adminpanel/webapi/accountadd',
        data: AddForm.serialize()
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.result) {
                AddForm.trigger("reset");
                $("#AccountAddModal").modal('toggle');
                table.ajax.reload();
            } else {$("#AccountAddModal").modal('toggle');}

        }).fail(function(data) {

    });
})
```

The form code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AccountAddModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form action="#" id="add-form" class="smart-form client-form" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <input type="text" name="names" placeholder="First name">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <input type="text" name="lastnames" placeholder="Last name">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-phone"></i>
                                <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" data-mask="(999) 999-9999">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Register
                </button>
            </div>
            </footer>   
        </form> 
    </div>
</div><
```

i have tried these solutions but i still having the trouble when you click fast you can submit more than one time, and to add a new user you have to refresh the page

Comment: You can disable the button with
`document.getElementById("button's_id_here").disabled = true;`
or with jQuery `$("#button's_id_here").prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: *"How can I disable the button after the first click?"*  Disable it by setting the attribute?

Comment: @epascarello by JQuery `$("btn_id").click(function(){});` Function you can disable it after first click. To disable use `$("#btn_id").prop("disabled","true");`

Comment: not sure why you mentioned me @AAShakil

Comment: @epascarello Oops, sorry. You replied and I thought you as the questioner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in the button's click event handler.

```
if ( !document.getElementById("button's_id_here").disabled )
   document.getElementById("button's_id_here").disabled = true;

    //rest of the button's click handler here
```

or with jQuery

```
if ( !$("#button's_id_here").attr("disabled")  )
   $("#button's_id_here").attr("disabled", true);

    //rest of the button's click handler here
```

Comment: the trouble is my button doesnt have an id

Comment: You can either add an id to button, or you can use jQuery to find the required button, like
`$("div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-primary").attr("disabled")` 
will give you the status of the `submit` button.

Comment: You can add an id like `<button id="submit_Register" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">` or some other id that you would like.

Comment: nice, the problem is that  it just doesnt let me click it from the start. it appears disabled from the start

Comment: Try removing the class `modal fade`, and I think you are missing a closing div tag at the end of the HTML.

Comment: ok yes, this work, ut i still having the trouble when you click fast you can submit more than one time, and to add a new user you have to refresh the page

Comment: This happens because Ajax call is async. And it takes some time to get results. When you click fast, the the second click happens before the results are returned. You will have to add the button disabling if condition in the AddForm.submit (function  (e) {}): like I mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it plain javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById("add-form").disabled = true;
```

This disables the button.
Just add it to the submit function callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button with the following jquery code:

```
$(#buttonid).attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Place it in your on click function

Comment: this doesnt let me click at first, it disable the button from start